# Attaching a document to an item

Tags: attachments, custom-field-types

Is there any way in SP 2007 of showing a column name and a file attachments dialog similar to the one that is displayed when clicking the link 'Attach' on a an list's newform.aspx but as a list column within the newform.aspx page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this forum post on MSDN might be of some help:

[Add attachment column to copy of NewForm.aspx in sharepoint designer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/01a19d14-28fd-45df-949c-c6ad033d2d58)

> For your scenario, I think you can try to create a custom list form
>   (create custom list form), and then you can use SharePoint control
>   “Form Action Button” instead of the default “Ok” button in the custom
>   list form:
>
> 1. Open the new list form in SharePoint Designer;
> 2. Delete the “OK” button.
> 3. Insert a “Form Action Button” in the same place: In “Insert” menu > select “SharePoint Controls”> select “More SharePoint
>      Controls”>select “Form Action Button”
> 4. There will has a “Form Actions” dialog box, select “Commit” and “Navigate to page “actions for this button> click “Navigate to page “
>      and click “settings”> set the page URL.